# Extract two values from a line using regex in bash script

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have multiple strings that are similar to the following format:

> Hi there Andre (91234342), currently our records show that on 2016-10-24 you were found ...

I need to extract both the number in brackets which is always an 8 digit number and the date which is always in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format. They do not always appear in the same order in the string though.

The output needs to look like: 
`2016-10-24 91234342`

I have tried using `sed` to get the values I want but can only manage to get one value using `sed`.

Can anyone offer some help/advice?

Thank you!

Comment: you should switch to more powerful options like `perl` because it becomes increasingly difficult when the number of groups to be captured increases

Comment: @rock321987 sed is fine for this...

Comment: @123 that's why I told `if the number of groups increase`

Comment: @rock321987 sed is still okay even with more groups.

Comment: @123 what happens if the ordering does not matter for 5 groups? All combinations have to be formed

Comment: @rock321987 it would be a longer command, not necessarily more difficult.

Comment: @123 agree but it would become more obfuscated..

Answer (score 1):

Just use 2 expressions to satisfy both formats of ordering like this:

```
$ cat file 
Hi there Andre (91234342), currently our records show that on 2016-10-24 you were found ...
Hi there Andre 2016-10-24, currently our records show that on (91234342) you were found ...
$ sed -r -e 's/^.*\(([0-9]{8})\).*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*$/\2 \1/' -e 's/^.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*\(([0-9]{8})\).*$/\1 \2/' file
2016-10-24 91234342
2016-10-24 91234342
$
```

this is the 1st expression for line having date after 8 digit number:
`-e 's/^.*\(([0-9]{8})\).*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*$/\2 \1/'`

and this expression is for the reverse order:
`-e 's/^.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*\(([0-9]{8})\).*$/\1 \2/'`

Comment: Why is the `'g'` necessary? Why is the hyphen (`\-`) escaped?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yeah its un-necessary .. fixed it thnx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -r 's/.*\(([0-9]{8})\).*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*/\2 \1/;s/.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*\(([0-9]{8})\).*/\1 \2/' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Following regex should work

```
.+\((\d{8})\).+(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}).+
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. The other answers have already shown the use of *extended regular expression* syntax, but you can also make use of regular expressions with a slight adjustment to syntax, and you can create a short script to eliminate repetitive typing.

For example basic syntax would be:

```
$ sed -e "s/^.*[(]\([0-9]\{8\}\)[)].*\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\).*$/\2 \1/;
s/^.*\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\).*[(]\([0-9]\{8\}\)[)].*$/\1 \2/" file.txt
```

**Example file.txt**

```
$ cat file.txt
Hi there Andre (91234342), currently our records show that on 2016-10-24 you were found ...
Hi there Andre 2016-10-24, currently our records show that on (91234342) you were found ...
```

Using the regular expression above gives:

```
2016-10-24 91234342
2016-10-24 91234342
```

**Using variables within a script**

You can make use of variables to keep the regular expression and substitute command legible. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

digits='[(]\([0-9]\{8\}\)[)]'
pdate='\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\)'

sed -e "s/^.*${digits}.*${pdate}.*$/\2 \1/;
s/^.*${pdate}.*${digits}.*$/\1 \2/" \
"$1"
```

**Output**

```
$ bash sedcmd.sh file.txt
2016-10-24 91234342
2016-10-24 91234342
```

Either way, with regular or extended syntax, just find some way to save the expression so you don't have to risk re-typing it `:)`